# Selecting everything but not a specific value

Tags: sql

I have a table called Proofs which has columns (ID, proof) I am trying to select the ID and Proof, however their is a certain value in the proof column for example "All proofs" I want to see everything except "All proofs" in the execution, what SQL query would I have to do?

Comment: @sam...what database are you using?  What queries have you tried so far?  Need more detail in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Proofs p
WHERE p.Proof <> 'All proofs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Select ID, Proof
from Proofs
where Proofs.Proof <> 'All proofs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
select * from Proofs where Proof != "All proofs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
select * from table where Proof NOT IN ('All proofs')
```

And keep adding values to exclude inside the parentheses as they come up..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
select * from PROOFS where Proof <> 'All proofs'
```

Or if your string is inside a bigger text:

```
SELECT * FROM PROOFS where Location NOT LIKE '%All proofs%'
```